# Shell exec command with | fails

Tags: shell

I write a script with  | in command , it run fail .

```
#! /bin/bash

 datestr=`date -d '-1 day' '+%Y-%m-%d'`
 cmd="cat /service/domain_detect/api/storage/logs/laravel.log | grep sub_domain | grep $datestr | wc -l"
 echo $cmd
 count=$($cmd)
 echo $count
```

Expected output is the result line num. 
The actual result is follow:

```
cat /service/domain_detect/api/storage/logs/laravel.log | grep sub_domain | grep 2019-01-17 | wc -l
cat: invalid option -- 'l'
Try 'cat --help' for more information.
```

Comment: Are you sure that the first line of your shell script is correct declared?

Comment: any reason why don't you use a function?